# Not able to install on few devices

Tags: android, android-manifest

My problem is very strange. I tried Google it, but no where i have found answer. I have uploaded my application to Play store. Our customers able to install it to their devices and few of our customers are not able to install my application. I suggested them to Turn off their WiFi and turn on again. Then they are able to install it. How to resolve this problem? These are the permissions that i'm using

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Is there any relation to app permission to installation of app?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you specify writeexternalstorage twice?

Comment: It could be permissions or minimum android version. We had such problem with flashlight, for this case we specified  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" android:required="false" /> that it's not required, but I don't see unconventional permissions in your list which can be unavailable on most of the devices.

Comment: The double permission should not be an issue. Once the user agreed to download you application with the set of permissions you mentioned in your manifest it should be downloaded and installed. How big is your app?

Comment: Do these devices correspond to minimum sdk version?

Comment: It's size is 1.2MB. And all the devices corresponds to minimum SDK version